# Dynamic return type based on the input - asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, function, dynamic

I want to create a function which would have two parameters

```
public **XYZ** GetOputput(string strToConvert, **ABC**)
```

What I want from this function, that I will send a string to this function and the datatype in which I want to convert this string [Ex: Int32,Int64, datetime etc..] and the return will be the same as the datatype I have sent as the input parameter.

I want to have something like this in my function:

```
 switch(//what is the data type)

                case: //if data type is date than do something and return date
                case: //if data type is int than do something and return int
```

I have no idea how to send, compare and return the datatype dynamically.
Assist me

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How about using a generic function.

```
  public T GetValue<T>(string value)
  {
     return (T)Convert.ChangeType(value, typeof(T), CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
  }
```

So to get an int from a string, try this:

```
int x = GetValue<int>("1234");
```

Comment: @massif and I have the same idea.  However, Culture Info is very important.

Answer (score 3):

You can use this for your function (takes nullable types into consideration):

```
public T GetValue<T>(string value)
    {
        return (T)Convert.ChangeType(value, Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(typeof(T)) ?? typeof(T));
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

use `dynamic`, if you are using .NET framework 4.0

Comment: Thanks for the quick response but I am using .NET 3.5 :-(

Comment: @Chris: See options on using Generics, but your best bet would be to use an object as return type and as 'Mika' said using Convert.ChangeType

Comment: @Chris: Massif has given a solution using generics!

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [Convert.ChangeType](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.convert.changetype.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you want to use Generics:

```
public T GetOutput<T>(string input)
{
//DoStuff
}
```

And in use:

```
var int = GetOutput<int>("10");
```

Although inspecting the type of T for all accepted types could be a bit tedious.

edit: So combine it with Mika's answer and do:

```
public T GetOutput<T>(string input)
{
    return (T)Convert.ChangeType(input, typeof(T));
}
```